# Python smtplib authentication OR server TLS error

Tags: python, python-2.7, smtplib

I have the following Python code that is used to send email via a SMTP server in our corporate domain. It had been working perfectly till two days ago.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

SERVER = "EMAIL-SERVER.DOMAIN.COM"
AUTH_USER = 'auth_user@DOMAIN.COM'
AUTH_PWD = 'auth_password'

FROM_EMAIL = AUTH_USER
TO_EMAILS = 'MYSELF@DOMAIN.COM'
CC_EMAILS = ''
BCC_EMAILS = ''

s = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER, 25)
s.set_debuglevel(1)
msg = MIMEText("""body""")
sender = AUTH_USER
recipients = [TO_EMAILS]
msg['Subject'] = "subject line"
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)

s.starttls()
s.ehlo()
s.login(AUTH_USER, AUTH_PWD)
s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())

s.quit()
```

When I ran the code above, it gave the following logs:

```
send: 'ehlo MY_SERVER\r\n'
reply: '250-SMTP_SERVER_NAME Hello [SMTP_SERVER_IP]\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE\r\n'
reply: '250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: '250-DSN\r\n'
reply: '250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: '250-XXXXXXXXXXXXXA\r\n'
reply: '250-AUTH NTLM\r\n'
reply: '250-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXB\r\n'
reply: '250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: '250-BINARYMIME\r\n'
reply: '250-XXXXXXXC\r\n'
reply: '250-XXXXXXD\r\n'
reply: '250-XXXXE\r\n'
reply: '250 XXXXXXF\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: SMTP_SERVER_NAME Hello [SMTP_SERVER_IP]
SIZE
PIPELINING
DSN
ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
XXXXXXXXXXXXXA
AUTH NTLM
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXB
8BITMIME
BINARYMIME
XXXXXXXC
XXXXXXD
XXXXE
XXXXXXF
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestSMTP.py", line 23, in <module>
    s.starttls()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\lib\smtplib.py", line 626, in starttls
    raise SMTPException("STARTTLS extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPException: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.
```

Then I tried to comment out `s.starttls()`, then a different error was thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestSMTP.py", line 25, in <module>
    s.login(AUTH_USER, AUTH_PWD)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\lib\smtplib.py", line 600, in login
    raise SMTPException("No suitable authentication method found.")
smtplib.SMTPException: No suitable authentication method found.
```

Is it a TLS issue with the SMTP server or an authentication error?

Comment: Perhaps the server now only supports SSL but not TLS?

Comment: @Sraw Thanks. Also tried s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("EMAIL-SERVER.DOMAIN.COM:465"), and it failed with the error "socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"